# Retrieve Excel Workbook Connection Properties

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am attempting to grab the "Command Text" from the Connection Property window in an Excel file using python. However, I cannot find the object that contains this information. In the below picture I would like to retrieve the highlighted `EXEC sp_FooBar` as a string:

[image]

I am able to retrieve the Connection *names* with:

```
import odbc
import win32com.client
file = r'PATH_TO_FILE'
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.workbooks.open(file)
for x in wb.connections:
    print(x)
```

But I'm not sure how to use the `<COMObject <unknown>>` object further to grab the command text. I'm thinking `win32com` may have something, but can't seem to crack the code.

Comment: Complete shot in the dark here, but is it possible that `commandtext` is a property of `connections`? Perhaps `.connections.oledbconnection.commandtext`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `CommandText` property from a `OLEDBConnection`instance like this:

```
import odbc
import win32com.client

file = r'PATH_TO_FILE'
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.workbooks.open(file)
for x in wb.Connections:
    print(x.OLEDBConnection.CommandText)
xl.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: this is amazing. Do you have any links to documentation on the OLEDBConnection instance? I want to know *how* you solved this, as I'm sure I'll have future needs similar to this question

Comment: The documentation that exists is the one from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model). You can find all the references there.

Comment: Your solutions work well with the xlsx files, but I am unable to open the xlsm file, the code just spins indenfinitely. Is there a way to see the connections in the xlsm? Thanks.